# ¿Cómo traducir el nombre "Queen Watevra Wa'Nabi" manteniendo el juego de palabras?

Tags: traducción, concurso-de-popularidad

Cuando a mis hijos les da por una película, son de los que la piden una vez, y otra, y otra, hasta que al final me acabo aprendiendo yo la película mejor que ellos. La última ha sido *[La Lego Película 2](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt3513498/?ref_=nv_sr_srsg_0)*, y en ella aparece un personaje que es capaz de adoptar la forma que le dé la gana, llamado en inglés Queen Watevra Wa'Nabi.

[image: Soyloque Quiera]

Entiendo que en inglés se ha hecho un juego de palabras para que la expresión "whatever wannabe" parezca un nombre más o menos real. Sin embargo, las traducciones que he visto al español son:

- Reina Soyloque Quiera. Usado en España.
- Reina Loquequieraser. Usado en Hispanoamérica.

Ambas traducciones son literales, pero en ningún caso me parece que se asemejen a nombres reales. Pensaba que un juego de palabras tipo "Aitor Tilla" o "Pancho Colate" habría quedado más divertido, pero claro, es muy difícil encontrar algo así que encima mantenga el juego de palabras original.

Así pues, y para intentar estrenar un nuevo estilo de preguntas basado en los concursos de popularidad, ¿qué se os ocurre a vosotros? Demos rienda suelta a nuestra imaginación combinada con nuestro conocimiento del idioma, e inventemos nombres más divertidos que mantengan el juego de palabras original para este personaje.

¡La respuesta más votada será la ganadora!

Comment: Como siempre que pregunto cosas que bordean los límites del sitio, si os parece que es off-topic no os cortéis en proponer su borrado. Si os parece que encaja en el sitio espero que la disfrutemos entre todos. :-)

Comment: Esta pregunta está formulada partiendo de la base de que la comunidad ha aceptado los concursos de popularidad o no? Yo votaría por off topic, salvo que la comunidad haya decidido admitir este tipo de preguntas, como juego o preguntas normal

Comment: @Diego la propuesta [se planteó en Meta](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3242/12637), y la única participación que tuvo fue a favor, aunque desde luego fue escasa. Así que directamente preferí hacer la propuesta con un ejemplo, que así tiene más visibilidad. Si te parece offtopic, como digo vota para cerrarla con toda tranquilidad.

Comment: Plantearé allí un par de apuntes entonces. Para mí esto sería off-topic, salve que hemos decidido en meta que no (aunque a mi gusto, un poco rápido y tal vez los concursos de popularidad deberían ser juegos como el translation golf y por tanto tanto preguntas como respuestas community wiki)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dado que Kika es un nombre de mujer, yo propongo

> Kika Maleónica

Podría funcionar casi igual con Erika o Francisca, pero con Kika mola más porque suena como "qué camaleónica"

Comment: Me gusta @Diego, por eso uno de los votos es mío, pero tengo que decir que, en aras de la precisión semántica, la versión del camaleón no es totalmente representativa por cuanto este, **muta de color pero *no de forma***, cómo si lo hace el personaje de la película

Answer (score 3):

> Queen **Watevra Wa'Nabi**

---

> Reina **Zoila Ke'Kiera**

Comment: La pongo separada porque para mi esta versión encuentra el sentido, la cacofonía (repetición musical) y el aire africano del personaje

Answer (score 2):

Se me ocurre lo siguiente:

> Rebeca Maleón

Answer (score 2):

Jaja, muy bueno, voy aportando:

> **Reina**...
>    
>    / Betty Ciencaras 
>    / Gloria Tramutante 
>    / Eva Mul Tirostros 
>    / Berta Antascaras 
>    / Clara EsMil Formas 
>    / Monica Sosmiles 
>    / Sara Soyquienquiero
>
> ---
>
> / Erica Rasmúltiples
>
> ---
>
> /  Mireya Mutó 
>   /  Jesica Ambiante 
>   /  Nayra Pidamuda 
>   /  Samira Quetantas 
>   /  Zoraida Sorpresas 
>   /  Judit Antascaras
>
> ---
>
> /  Veronica Rasmudables

Después de ver el trailer, me gusta algo del aire exótico con el que suena una de las opciones, cómo para que el personaje se presente diciendo:

> soy la reina **Nayra Pidam"Uda**

Siguiendo la búsqueda de nombrar un personaje capaz de adoptar cualquier forma e identidad

> **Queen Watevra Wa'Nabi**

podría ser

> Reina Reinve 'Ntable

(jugando con algo de parecida repetición sonora (cacofónica)

Comment: La última la dejas como "Erica Rasmúltiples" y mola. :-D

Comment: Si, ahí la volví a poner así.

Answer (score 2):

Usando "Paca" [hipocorístico](http://www.academia.org.mx/espin/respuestas/item/pepe-paco-y-pancho-hipocoristicos) de Francisca

> Paca Mbiaformas

Paca (Francisca) es ciertamente un nombre como los que se proponen en la pregunta (Aitor, Pancho) que suena bastante español. A la vez, el apellido "Mbiaformas" suena (por lo menos para mi gusto) un pelín a algo exótico con ese "Mbia". Este apellido "raruno" se parece un poco al original en el que, aunque no he visto la película, ese  "Watevra Wa'Nabi" suena como si le quisiesen dar un toque africano.

Si "Mbiaformas" no es un apellido molón, podríamos pasarlo a

> Paca Mbiante

Comment: "Paca Biafor más", en inglés se juega mucho con que la pronunciación se parece pero no es igual, así que creo que podrías salirte con la tuya forzando un poco mas las palabras para que suenen a nombres medianamente posibles

Answer (score 0):

No sé si está permitido escribir más de una respuesta. Si lo está, ahí va otra:

> Carme Transformo

Answer (score 0):

La Reina Mía Quesea

Esto quedó demasiado corto, así que lo repitiré:

La Reina Mía Quesea